# Asynctask onProgressUpdate not called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm new to Android and Java programming. I have searched some examples and possible solutions for some hours and I still cannot make it work.

I'm doing a network operation and it works perfectly well (it does enter onPostExecute method) if I just execute it and print the result, so now I'm trying to make it work on a while loop (to update the ui constantly with the results) but it doesn't seem to enter onProgressUpdate.

The log shows me the network operation is working well but I cannot publish content on the textview since it never enters onProgressUpdate. I tried to clean my code and just used a for loop and I'm getting the same result:

```
public class loadsomestuff extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

    String result="";
    ProgressDialog Pd = null;

    protected void onPreExecute(){

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        Log.d("Inicio connexió","");
        for(int m=0;m<100;m++){
            String s = "string"+m;
            Log.i("Loop",s);
            publishProgress(s);
        }

        //Log.d("",result);
      return result;
    }
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String prova){
        super.onProgressUpdate(prova);
        Log.i("Trying to enter onProgressUpdate",prova);
      }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String abc){
        // Definim el textView i mostrem el resultat per pantalla
        Log.i("I can enter here",prova);
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian why you edited the question instead of answering it? Your edit seemed to be a bug fix...

Comment: You're getting the values in the prova String variable or only within the loop?

Comment: @donfuxx because public class loadsomestuff extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{ line have not 4 space..

Comment: @S.M_Emamian put your suggestions to fix this code as an answer then ;-)

Comment: @donfuxx "AsyncTask<String, String, String>" Why did you delete it?

Comment: @S.M_Emamian now I see... it looked like in original question there was no `<String, String, String>` on first view... but that was wrong. it was just not visible because stuff inside `<>` just got not displayed.. sorry for creating confusion.

Comment: @user3424020 solved your problem ?

Comment: I not really sure why it does have to be an array, but It's working perfect now, thank you very much :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chenge :

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(String prova){
    super.onProgressUpdate(prova);
    Log.i("Trying to enter onProgressUpdate",prova);
  }
```

to :

```
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String...prova){
        Log.e("Trying to enter onProgressUpdate",prova[0]);

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this example 
     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

Parameter is a array 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
Check this

Answer (score 0):

change :

protected void onProgressUpdate(String prova){
    super.onProgressUpdate(prova);
    Log.i("Trying to enter onProgressUpdate",prova);
  }

to :

@Override

protected void onProgressUpdate(String prova){
    super.onProgressUpdate(prova);
    Log.i("Trying to enter onProgressUpdate",prova);
  }